# bootstrap.min.js create problem for opening model popup in second time

Tags: javascript, php, css

I am trying to solve the proble and using 2 javascript but there are problem one time popup proper work but second time it is not open 
[FNP [Gardens][1]](https://m.fnpgardens.com)

```
<script src="http://localhost/fnpmobile2/wp-content/themes/gardens/js/custom-navigation.js"></script>   
<script src="http://localhost/fnpmobile2/wp-content/themes/gardens/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

but it given problem

Comment: Please edit your post again and submit a clear example.

Comment: Hi there Abhishek.

In order for the community to help you out, we do need more information than has been provided. What problems are occurring for example?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it